# SQL subquery with EXISTS (= finding the last record + data from other columns for each distinct value in one of the columns)

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

please for advice as nothing works for me. Find bellow simplified example.

I have such a table with machine and its changing status (each new status gets new RecordID):
[image]

from which I need to find out the present (latest) status by each machine, means this:
[image]

I have made up such a code:

```
SELECT TAB2.Machine, TAB2.Status
FROM DB.dbo.TAB TAB2
   WHERE EXISTS
   (
   SELECT MAX(TAB1.RecordID), TAB1.Machine
   FROM DB.dbo.TAB TAB1
   WHERE TAB1.RecordID= TAB2.RecordID
   GROUP BY TAB1.Machine
   )
```

The subquery works well and finds the last RecordID for each machine. But then the top select multiplies the rows.
Can you advice how to correct this query? Or is there some other better solution?

thanks for help, Tom

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
SELECT TAB2.Machine, TAB2.Status
FROM DB.dbo.TAB TAB2
WHERE TAB2.RecordID =
   (
   SELECT MAX(TAB1.RecordID)
   FROM DB.dbo.TAB TAB1
   WHERE TAB1.Machine = TAB2.Machine
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your correlated subquery will always have a result set, hence, all of the rows will be returned. i.e. the `max(recordid)` where `recordid =1` is equal to 1 !.

You could fix your query using the `NOT EXISTS` operator as the following:

```
SELECT TAB2.Machine, TAB2.Status
FROM TAB TAB2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
    SELECT 1 FROM TAB TAB1
    WHERE TAB1.Machine = TAB2.Machine AND TAB1.RecordID > TAB2.RecordID
 )
ORDER BY Machine
```

Another approach to solving your problem is to use the `ROW_NUMBER` function as the following:

```
SELECT Machine, Status
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Machine ORDER BY RecordID DESC) rn
  FROM TAB
) T
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Machine
```

[see a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/C18cr02t)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your intent was to *correlate* the subquery with the outer query, like so:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.recordid = (
    select max(t1.recordid)
    from mytable t1
    where t1.machine = t.machine
)
```

The subquery yields the latest recordid for the current machine, which we can use to filter the table.

In most databases, this can also be expressed using window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by machine order by recordid desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. Except "NOT EXISTS" I've successfully tested both options and both worked well!

Great.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).